# document.getElementById is null? ... what's wrong with my code..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Why am I getting "document.getelementbyId is null" ???
Any help is appreciate. thx. ... (and it says I need to type more text before I can submit... )

```
// get current date - in format
  function thisDate(){
    var today = new Date(),
     dd = today.getDate(),
     mm = today.getMonth() + 1, 
     yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10) {
      dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
      mm = '0' + mm
    }

    today = mm + ',' + dd + ',' + yyyy;

    dateDisplay =  document.getElementById('dateDisplay')[0];
    dateDisplay.innerHTML = today.toString();
    console.log(today);
  }
  thisDate();
```

Comment: Where is the HTML code with the element you're trying to get?

Comment: what is dateDisplay which control's id ? provide html please

Comment: `getElementById` just returns a single element and not a set of elements like `getElementByClassname`, so the [0] is 
unnecessary here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `[0]` from your `document.getElementById('dateDisplay')[0];`

`document.getElementById` does not return an array, so there is no point in having an index pointer.

Comment: If that was the only issue, the error message would be different. The other problem seems to be that the element is not found.

Comment: doh'.. completely missed it.. why you do not code at 4am..